# Delphis ZLib Interface not initialized

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, zlib

When working with Delphi XE2 I have the following problem:

When I try to compress a response from `IdHTTPServer` that should be sent to a client, I am not able to do this. The `IdCompressorZLib.CompressHTTPDeflate` or `IdCompressorZLib.CompressStream` functions always stop with the error `ZLib Error (-6)`. This means that Delphi does not find a library with the expected version. `ZLIB_VERSION` is set to 1.2.5 in my environment.

My question is what I have to do to get it working?

Comment: Why don't you use the `zlib` library that ships with Delphi? This avoids the need for an external DLL. The zlib objects are statically linked.

Comment: Hello,I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: No, that's not what happened. Your code did not work. The `zlib` library works.

Comment: The Lib for indy compression is linked statically as well. But it seems to be the wrong version. There are examples for IdHTTPServer and Indy compression on the web but not for system.zlib. I am not able to get it running.

Comment: Well, your mention of `ZLIB1.DLL` suggests dynamic linking.

Comment: there is a compiler directive in the indy stuff which is always defined: STATICLOAD_ZLIB. That lets me assume that the library is linked statically. The loadlibrary is never called.

Comment: OK, so I removed the references to DLLs that were confusing me. Now, which Indy are you using? Emba's version that came with XE2, or the latest Indy?

Comment: The indy version is 10.5.8.0. It came with delphi XE.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot help you any more I think. I'm sure you can use built in `zlib`, but since Indy offers zlib functionality I'd probably try to get that working.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've fired up XE2 and can reproduce what you report. It would seem that Embarcadero have blundered when building Indy for XE2. There is a mismatch between the zlib version of the linked objects, and the zlib version that is passed to the zlib initialization functions. Nothing you can do with what they shipped can work around that flaw.

Your options, as I see it:

1. Fix the version of Indy that was supplied with XE2. This will involve modifying the Indy source files and fixing the version mismatch. And then linking the modified Indy units to your application. Not impossible, but possibly a little awkward.
2. Use the latest version of Indy, obtained from the Indy project repo. You'll then have the latest and greatest Indy.
3. Use a different zlib library. For example the zlib library that ships with Delphi is known to work. I know you had trouble with this when I suggested it in a comment, but I for one have used it without trouble.
4. Use a different version of Delphi. Not a great option, but I'm including it for completeness.